# Hiding text in links when the document is printed

Tags: html, css

I am using a print page button and I am trying to hide the (click here to print) portion of the link when the document prints. (It also shows forms `(forms/IRF.cfm)` which I do not want to show either.)

```
<a href="forms/IRF.cfm" target="_blank">Initial Registration Fee Exemption Affidavit - if applicable (click here to print)</a>
```

I tried inserting span with a class of `noprint` to hide it with css and that did not work either.

```
@media print {
      .noprint {
        display: none;
      }
    }

<a href="forms/IRF.cfm" target="_blank">Initial Registration Fee Exemption Affidavit - if applicable <span class="noprint">(click here to print)</span></a>
```

Is there a special way to do this with text and links?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer if anyone is looking for this. To remove the paths of the href you will want to do this with the css:

```
@media print {
a[href]:after {
        content: none !important;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I try with your code it works perfectly:

```html
<style>
@media print {
      .noprint {
        display: none;
      }
    }
</style>

<a href="forms/IRF.cfm" target="_blank">Initial Registration Fee Exemption Affidavit - if applicable <span class="noprint">(click here to print)</span></a>
```

To test, please click "Run code snippet", then right-click next to the link "initial Registration...." and select "print".

Comment: Its not removing the path of the href its shows (forms/IRF.cfm) still. If you use class in the link it hides the entire link

Comment: @David Brierton: Sorry, I can't reproduce this - which browser are you using? I tried Chrome and IE 11. It does not display any URL information in the printed document.

Comment: I am using chrome as well. Then answer I posted below fixed it.